# Null return value from a nested async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query

How does this function returns null? is it because of the variable scope or execution time of the functions?

```
async function getBook() {
      var book;
      await libray.findONe({ cat: 1 }, {}, async (err, res) => {
        await section.findONe({ secId: res.secI }, {}, (error, result) => {
          book = result;
        });
      });
    
      book = result;
    }


return book;
}
```

Comment: You will never succeed here mixing callbacks and `await`.  `await` only does something useful when it's awaiting a promise and when you pass a callback to your database functions, they do not return a promise.  Please take a second to learn what `await` really does and how to use it and how to use promises with your database.  You can't just through and `await` in anywhere and expect it to do something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
async function getBook() {
      const res = await libray.findOne({ cat: 1 });
      const book = await section.findOne({ secId: res.secI });
      return book;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are returning from the function before the async function finishes.
so one convenient way to solve this is to make a callback function from the async function.

Sorry I am not a js guy so I can't actually post code but I think you got the idea..